# Repository Server - apt-mirror - How to report the list of downloaded packages on every run?

Tags: repository, apt-mirror

apt-mirror outputs the size of downloaded packages...
`167.3 MiB will be downloaded into archive.`

But how to report the list of downloaded packages on every run?

Example: `Following packages were downloaded: apache, chrome, ...`

Comment: @OrganicMarble would you share it?

Comment: Your question made me want to reexamine it, I put it in long ago. It's `find /[directory]/apt-mirror/mirror/* -mmin -60 | grep "pool" | sort` But I can't remember why I did the grep, or why I have the `*`. Something like this could probably work if someone who knows bash chimes in.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built-in, but `apt-mirror` is a fairly basic perl script.  If you are comfortable doing it then you could probably add a patch at https://github.com/apt-mirror/apt-mirror/blob/7d521b168ab34fd38fd38bbb26acad1f43e262a7/apt-mirror#L910 .

You could certainly use a Bash solution as a comment suggests if it suits your needs.  The `postmirror.sh` script would be a very handy location to run it.  A line like this will print packages updated in the past hour

```
find . -type f -path '*pool*' -mmin -60 -print
```

Unfortunately, `apt-mirror` is not actively developed.  There are several bugs that will prevent it from properly mirroring apt repositories for recent releases.  You could consider using a fork where these bugs have been patched.  If you do, then you could potentially request this feature from the fork maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a satisfactory way to list the packages.

In the `../apt-mirror/var` directory there's a file named `ALL`. I don't completely understand the format of this file, especially why some lines are duplicated in it, but for our purposes what matters is that it's a kind of catalog of the mirrored files.

To get started, save this file somewhere, I put it in `~/Documents` and called it `ALL_saved`.

Then add these lines to your `postmirror.sh` script

```
diff /media/[redacted]/apt-mirror/var/ALL /home/[redacted]/Documents/ALL_saved | sort | uniq | tee -a /home/[redacted]/mirror/mirror-$_now.txt
...
cp /media/[redacted]/apt-mirror/var/ALL /home/[redacted]/Documents/ALL_saved
```

So, after the mirror update script runs, the postmirror script will now compare the old copy of the catalog with the new one, printout the differences, and then update the saved copy. You end up with output like this:

```
> security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/t/thunderbird/thunderbird_115.4.1-1~deb12u1_amd64.deb
> security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/t/thunderbird/thunderbird_115.4.1-1~deb12u1_i386.deb
< security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/t/thunderbird/thunderbird_115.5.0-1~deb12u1_amd64.deb
< security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/t/thunderbird/thunderbird_115.5.0-1~deb12u1_i386.deb
```

which lists every .deb file added and removed, as desired.